# Does chip select disables whole SPI slave or just the SPI lines of that Slave?

Tags: microcontroller, spi

I have a doubt on SPI slaves.

When we pull up the Chip select line, does it disables the whole Slave ( Functionality ) or just the communication module of the slave.

Taking a Ex:
If we have a SPI ADC. When we Pull up the slave , will it disable the ADC conversion process also or just the SPI lines of the ADC will be disabled but the conversion will still in going on?

Comment: What does the data sheet for the actual device say about it?

Comment: After reading the whole datasheet properly I got the answer, The internal conversion remains active , just the SPI module of that slave gets disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but from the research I did while looking into the SPI bus on AVR MCU's, the SPI hardware in the chip works independently of the AVR core.  That is to say, whether or not there is data being transferred on the SPI bus, chip functionality shouldn't be directly affected.

I don't know what electronics you're using, but I would assume that toggling the chip-select has no effect on the core function of your peripherals.  When in doubt, reference the datasheet of your slave device.  It may have some useful insights on the particular SPI hardware.

I hope this helps.